# Adding 2 Object.keys to one array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am iterating over this in my html file to create a dynamic table header.
I have a nested object

```
$scope.tasks = [{ "Number": 159232, "Title": "BUG", "Status": "pending", "Link": "www.google.com", "Card": "www.kanban.com", "Point": { "Value": 1, "IsTimeBased": true }, "ApprovalStatus":{ "CR": true , "BA": true } };

$scope.titles = Object.keys($scope.tasks[0]);
```

This iterates through all the non nested items but I cant figure out how to add the keys from the nested object. 
I tried

```
$scope.titles.push(Object.keys($scope.tasks.ApprovalStatus[0]));
```

But nothing seems to be working I tried a splice in this fashion as well.

Comment: What exactly do you want `$scope.titles` to look like

Comment: a single array. when I do this$scope.titles.push(Object.keys($scope.tasks[0].ApprovalStatus)); t makes the array[Number, Title,.... [CR]]

Comment: @jshill103 I've updated my answer, please have a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.push` use `.concat`.

```
$scope.titles = $scope.titles.concat(Object.keys($scope.tasks.ApprovalStatus[0]));
```

You can also do the concat for multiple args simultaneously.